# Preimage of a submanifold is a submanifold - Transversality

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

It is  [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem) that if a smooth Map $f : M  \to N$ between two smooth manifolds (finite dimensional) is transversal to a submanifold $L \subset N, L \pitchfork f$, than $f^{-1}(N)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

According to the [german wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversalit%C3%A4t#Motivation) about transversality, the converse (if the preimage under a smooth map $f$ of a submanifold is also a submanifold, the map is transversal to N, so $f \pitchfork N$) is also true (and I didn’t find a proof of this).

I ask myself, whether that is true? According to  Serge Lang the usual definition involving the complimentary tangent spaces  is [equivalent](https://books.google.de/books?id=VfxGB5nYv1MC&lpg=PP1&dq=lang%20differential%20manifolds&hl=de&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q&f=false) to: A certain composition of maps is a submersion. Thus I would have to prove that this composition is a submersion, i.e. has regular values.

**EDIT**:
So apparently, in general this is false. To avoid confusion, I removed a part of the question describing a situation I thought I was finding myself in, which was not the case. I leave the general part of the question for anyone asking themselves this question.

Comment: In that generality the result is wrong. Take $M,N$ not $0$-dimensional and $f$ the constant map.

Comment: and also not true in generality: pick two embeddings of the 1-sphere into a higher dimensional space which are just tangent in one point. the preimage will just be a point.

Comment: Hello Dan, and thanks for the help. What you said is perfectly reasonable and helpful. Come to think of it, it is almost like the situation in the [picture in the English wikipedia entry](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Sphere-nontransverse.svg) (except the circles intersect only once in your example.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of one of my homeworks on this problem. Also you can look for an alternative idea of adapted charts in **section 9.10** Transversality theorem, from Loring W. Tu Intro to manifolds.

Consider the map $f: Dom \to Tar$, transversal to the regular submanifold $S$ (target) and show, that the preimage of it is a regular submanifold $f^{-1} S = S_d$ (domain). Also show
\begin{equation}
  T_{p}(S_d) \cong Df_p^{-1}(T_{f(p)} S)
 \end{equation}
Here we treat the right hand side as a subspace obtained as a preimage of another subspace under the linear map. We will see, that these linear subspaces coincide.

**proof**
Let's look at Lee, theorem 6.30 define $k =  dim Tar - dim S$
Given $x \in f^{-1}(S)$, we find $U \subset Tar$ and $\phi: U \to R^{k}$, $\phi^{-1}(0) = S \cap U$.

$f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(U)$ is the zero set of $\phi \circ f|_{F^{-1} U}$. We see, that all points in $f^{-1}(S) \cup f^{-1}(U)$ are inside the zero set, if a point is not in the preimage of $S$ it will get to the point in $U$ outside of $S$, which is mapped to non-zero.

Given $z \in T_0 R^k$, and $p \in f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(U)$.

There is $y \in T_{f(p)} Tar$ s.t. $D \phi_{f(p)} y = z$.

If $f$ is transverse to $S$, this means, that $y = y_0 + Df_p(v)$, where $y_0 \in T_{f(p)}S$, and $v \in T_p Dom$.

Recall, that the tangent space to the regular level submanifold is identified with the kernel of the differential map. $\ker D\phi_{f_p} = T_{f(p)} S$,  $D\phi_{f(p)} y_0 = 0$.
\begin{equation}
   D (\phi \circ f)(v) = D\phi_{f(p)} ( D f_p (v)) = D\phi_{f(p)} (y_0 + D f_p (v)) = z
  \end{equation}
Proved surjectivity. This means, that  $f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(U)$ is a level set of a regular map, hence we have a regular submanifold $S_d$.
\begin{equation}
  T_{p}(S_d) \cong Df_p^{-1}(T_{f(p)} S)
  \end{equation}
Now see that $T_p S_d = \ker D (\phi \circ f) = D (\phi \circ f) ^{-1}(0) =  Df_p^{-1}(T_{f(p)} S)$.